# Having problems telling a div to change sizes based on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making site in Dreamweaver(with bootstrap.) I am trying to tell the div to be at 75% width when screen is larger then 992px, and 100% width when screen is smaller then 992px. Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
}
 .bar {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #C54345;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
}
 .bar {
   width: 75%;
   background-color: #C54345;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have brackets in the wrong places, you've closed the media query braces immediately after you opened them! otherwise the code is fine.
Your code should look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .bar {
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #C54345;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
     .bar {
       width: 75%;
       background-color: #C54345;
    }
}
```

working **demo** [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrvdZo?editors=110)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am kind of new to this, and this is my first time with bootstrap. Thank you again!

Comment: glad to hear. If the answer helped you, accepting it by clicking the big tick will help future visitors know the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It very well could be being overridden. A good way to check this is by launching your project in the browser and using the Developer Tools to see what CSS is being overridden denoted by a slash going through it.

Typically though, I wouldn't take this sort of approach. I don't know your exact situation, but doing this isn't really going to cut it in the terms of standards.

Instead, because you're using bootstrap, I suggest looking in to "hidden-xs"/"visible-xs" classes built in to bootstrap. I'm guessing you're trying to do something different on a tablet than you would a larger screen size or vice-versa.

Comment: This is my first time working with bootstrap. @media seems to be the best way. If there is a better way you know of i would love to know!

Comment: Ah. I see the problem. You are actually not formatting your code correctly. `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
 .bar {
   width: 100%,
   background-color: #C54345;
}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .bar {
   width: 75%,
   background-color: #C54345;
}}` Try that.

Comment: Your brackets are in the wrong place and you're using ';' instead of ',' inside of your blocks. You only use ';' on the last line of your block. Technically, you don't even need to use the ';' at the end of your blocks.

Comment: Thank you. For the ";" Dreamweaver adds those every line i noticed.

Comment: @AndrewBudziszek that's not right. the placement of the `;` semi colons is correct.

Comment: here is a [working demo - using your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwyxxL?editors=110)  - it doesnt work because its invalid syntax. CSS property statements should be terminated with semicolons. If you replace the comma with the original semicolon - the demo works again